# Removing properties of an object starting by a parameter

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like some advice to return the properties of an object where others are deleted using lodash.
Example :

```
deletePropsThatStarsWith({a:1, b:2, aa:3}, 'a') //ouputs {b:2}
```

So far this is what is working but i don't know where i need to go.

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, aa: 3 }

function deletePropsThatStartsWith(object, prop) {
  return _.omit(object, prop)
}

console.log(deletePropsThatStartsWith(obj, 'a'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for help/advices.

Comment: You don't need lodash for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the lodash `_.omitBy` method. You can pass a callback for the second parameter, which decides which properties to omit. The callback will be invoked with two arguments, `value` and `key`.

So for your example, all you need is to check the key, and see if it starts with the desired string. The `.startsWith` method will be a good choice, or if you can't use that, lodash itself provides a `_.startsWith` method.

Example:

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, aa: 3}

function deletePropsThatStartsWith(object, prop) {
  return _.omitBy(object, (v, k) => k.startsWith(prop))
}

console.log(deletePropsThatStartsWith(obj, 'a'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `lodash` for this, try to implement it by yourself:

```
function deletePropsThatStartsWith(object, letter) {
    var newObjc = {}
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
        if (!key.startsWith(letter)) {
            newObjc = { ...newObjc, [key]: object[key] }
        }
    })

    return newObjc
}

const objc = { a: 1, b: 2, aa: 3 }
console.log(deletePropsThatStartsWith(objc, 'a'))
```

The output is `{ b: 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can get the object keys and not use lodash at all. This is built into vanilla js (my favorite JS framework!)

```
function deletePropsThatStartsWith(oldObject, prop) {
  let newObject = {};
  Object.keys(oldObject).forEach(k => {
    if (k.startsWith(prop)) continue;
    newObject[k] = oldObject[k];
  });
  return newObject;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // without lodash
    function deletePropsThatStartsWith(obj, prop) {
      var keys = Object.keys(obj);
      var newObj = {};
      for(var i = 0;i < keys.length;i++){
        if(keys[i][0] !== prop){
          newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]]
        }
      }
      return newObj;
    }
    console.log(deletePropsThatStartsWith({a:1,b:2,aa:3},'a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple for..in loop:

```js
function deletePropsThatStartsWith(object, prop) {
  let copy = {};
  for (key in object) {
    if (!key.startsWith(prop)) 
      copy[key] = object[key]
  };
  return copy;
}

var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, aa: 3 }

console.log(deletePropsThatStartsWith(obj, "a"));
```